# jQuery Mobile Panel & Media Queries

Tags: css, html, jquery-mobile, media-queries, panel

I have a panel on my jQuery Mobile Page like this:

http://pastebin.com/SB1SdhET

and this media query here:

http://pastebin.com/2tTWTip9

I use this to reduce the size of the page when the user visits the page on a desktop. Anyhow, when I use the media query and click the "buttons" inside the panel the panel closes like I am pressing outside of the panel...
how can I use media queries and jquery mobile panels in a correct way?

edit: http://jsfiddle.net/htu85b0w/1/

relevant code:

```
<div data-role='panel' id='panel' data-display='overlay'>
    <ul data-role='listview'>
        <li>
            <a href='https://printsrv2.rz.hs-offenburg.de/index.php' data-rel='external' data-role='button' data-icon='arrow-r' data-inline='true' data-ajax='false' target='_blank'>Druckaufträge</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href='#uploadPage' data-rel='close' data-role='button' data-icon='delete' data-inline='true'>Schließen</a>
        </li>
    </ul>  
</div>
```

I made a jsfiddle as requested, you need to expand the result view to the maximum (your screen must be big enough for this) to see the problem

Comment: Can you make a fiddle of your complete code(http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: see my edit in the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick solution is to make the panel dismiss layer appear below the panel using z-index. By default the panel has a z-index of 1001 and the dismiss div has 1002. In your media query, you can set the dismiss div z-index to 999:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 30em) {
        .ui-page {
                width: 30em !important;
                margin: 0 auto !important;
                position: relative !important;
                border: 1px solid lightgrey !important;
                border-radius: 15px;
                padding: 10px;
        }

        .ui-panel-dismiss {
                z-index: 999;    
        }
}
```

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/htu85b0w/3/)**

NOTE: if you want to be more thorough, you could size and position the dismiss div on panel open.

Comment: what do you mean with "on panel open"?
isn't the z-index solution thorough enough? =)
Anyhow, quick, easy and good explained. Thank you very much.

Comment: @ConquerorsHaki the panel has an open event you can use: http://api.jquerymobile.com/panel/#event-open.  However I think the CSS is enough. With your changes the dismiss div is not covering the whole page beneath the panel, so you could add extra CSS that sizes it...